# Sequelize.js - Asynchronous validators

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is it possible to have an asynchronous validator using Sequelize.js? I want to check for the existence of an association before saving a model. Something like this:

```
User = db.define("user", {
    name: Sequelize.STRING
},
{
    validate:
        hasDevice: ->
            @getDevices().success (devices) ->
                throw Exception if (devices.length < 1)
              return
})

# .... Device is just another model

User.hasMany(Device)
```

Or is there a way to force that check to run synchronously? (not ideal)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use asynchronous validations in v2.0.0.
It works like this:

```
var Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
  attr: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
  validate: {
    hasAssociation: function(next) {
      functionThatChecksTheAssociation(function(ok) {
        if (ok) {
          next()
        } else {
          next('Ooops. Something is wrong!')
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```